# jquery validation - breaking on change?

Tags: jquery

Here is our code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajLkz/1/

Basically, if we wrap the `if statements` for each input box in a jquery function like change or keyup - the whole thing returns true for everything.

Basically what we are aiming for is if EVERY if statement returns false, the button then becomes full opacity and disabled false.

But we want to put these if statements in a jquery change/keyup function.

Its really starting to annoy me >.<

Comment: You should use jquery validate http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: I don't want to use something premade, I want to make it myself. If you hire a chef you're never going to learn to cook.

Comment: this code made my eyes bleeding ! you should trigger the event when an input is blurred and then test all the inputs in the form to check if they are empty or not (if they are not you can enable the button)

Comment: empty isnt validation though Oddantfr

Comment: @422 did I say the contrary ?

Answer (score 0):

is that resolving the problem ?

[jsfiddle.net/ajLkz/3](http://jsfiddle.net/ajLkz/11/)